# What's the burn:/// thing - can it be used to burn a DVD?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, burning

I'm using 16.04 and Ubuntu Gnome with Nemo as my file manager. When I insert a blank DVD a Files (Nemo) window pops up blank with a URI of `burn:///`. I put some folders in here thinking I would then be able to burn them, but there's no button or menu action to do it?

What's the point of `burn:///` and how would we use it? (perhaps it's a nautilus only thing?)